# How to handle special Bootstrap events in React?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, reactjs

In straight up jQuery, I can do something like

```
$('#myCollapsible').on('click', 'hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

but is there a "right" way to do it in React? If the above is the way to go, where should I place that event handler? Please note that I am *not* using the react-bootstrap plugin.

Answer (score 23):

The right way to handle events not directly supported by React is by adding an event listener to the DOM node **after the component mounts**, and removing it when the component unmounts:

```js
class MyCollapsible extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    // Bind the method in the constructor instead of binding it in render, so you only do it once
    this.handleHiddenBsCollapse = this.handleHiddenBsCollapse.bind(this)
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.myCollapsible.addEventListener('hidden.bs.collapse', this.handleHiddenBsCollapse)
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.myCollapsible.removeEventListener('hidden.bs.collapse', this.handleHiddenBsCollapse)
  }

  handleHiddenBsCollapse(event) {
    // Do something...
  }

  render() {
    // Settings refs with node => this.bla = node is recommended
    // because this.refs is deprecated.
    // in this example "node" is the DOM node itself, not a react reference
    return (
      <div ref={node => (this.myCollapsible = node)} />
    )
  }
}
```

Documentation for using DOM refs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Weird. I'm not getting the events. When I look at the node in Chrome tools, the handlers are there. The handlers I added with jQuery `$('.panel').on("hidden.bs.collapse", tc);` show up as being on `hide` and `show` and they trigger.

Comment: Check to see that your bindings are correct in the react version. Also try `(foo, bar) => this.handleHiddenBsCollapse(foo, bar)` as the event handler in `addEventListener` to see what exactly you're getting.

Comment: I think the problem is that jQuery events are "namespaced" in a way that doesn't work with addEventListeners.

Comment: @FaustoNA I am trying to do something similar with functional component. I am able to trigger event on dropdown close but I also want to access selected element. My problem is that inside triggered function selected items array is always empty.

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm more than two years late to answer this question but I ran into this same problem recently and [Fausto NA](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5293590/fausto-na)'s answer didn't work for me. I was able to successfully attach my event listeners by leveraging the affected component's `componentDidMount` method:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import React from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        $('#myCollapsible').on('click', 'hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            alert('#myCollapsible -- hidden.bs.collapse');
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            // This is the render method where `#myCollapsible` would be added to the DOM. 
        )
    }
}
```

Why this works: if you try attaching an event handler to an element that isn't currently in the DOM then jQuery won't be able to successfully attach an event to it. In the example above, the jQuery code within the `componentDidMount` method doesn't run until `#myCollapsible` is in the DOM. This ensures jQuery can find it and properly attach your event handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you're building functional component, you should use useEffect hook.

Also maybe you'll need to use `window.$("#myCollapsible")` instead of `$("#myCollapsible")`

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react'
import $ from 'jquery'

export default function MyComponent() {
    useEffect(() => {
        // This code runs when component is mounted:
        window.$("#myCollapsible").on('hidden.bs.collapse', function (e) {
            console.log('hidden.bs.collapse');
        });
        return () => { // This code runs when component is unmounted
            window.$("#myCollapsible").off('hidden.bs.collapse');
        }
    }, []);

    // ...
}
```