# How to access updated state from event handler in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a component in reactjs based on functional component. I am trying to do exact thing mentioned in below link. I have a bootstrap dropdown, on close of dropdown I want to do callback to parent component by passing selected items.

[How to handle special Bootstrap events in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698746/how-to-handle-special-bootstrap-events-in-react)

Problem I am facing is that on dropdown close parent component's callback is getting called but with empty selected items.

code is here: [how to call ".hidden.bs.dropdown" event using jquery inside react function component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411103/how-to-call-hidden-bs-dropdown-event-using-jquery-inside-react-function-compo?noredirect=1#comment113896215_64411103)